# change _score in elasticsearch to make equal to doc's score field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have score (integer) field in data, I'm getting data from api, and posting it directly to localhost:9200//listings/
And I want the item _score to be equal to score field in data.

For now a solution is to add `?sort=score:desc` to url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a [`function_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) query, where you replace the default `_score` using a [`field_value_factor`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) score function. It goes like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/listings/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
              "field": "score",         <---- we use the score field instead
              "factor": 1,              <---- take the exact same score
              "missing": 1              <---- use 1 as score if the score field is missing
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace"           <---- we're replacing the default _score
    }
  }
}'
```

So we're basically computing the score using the `score` field multiplied by 1 and if any document doesn't have the `score` field we just assume the score to be 1 (you can change that to whatever makes more sense in your case).

**UPDATE**

According to your comment, you need the `_score` to be multiplied by the document's `score` field. You can achieve it simply by removing the `boost_mode` parameter, the default `boost_mode` is to `multiply` the `_score` with whatever value comes out of the `field_value_factor` function.

If you need to completely replace the default scoring mechanism to be based on your `score` field instead, there's a more complex way using the [`similarity` module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html), where you can define another similarity algorithm solely for your `score` field. There is a great [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-similarity-in-elasticsearch) explaining the nitty gritty details of the similarity module.

Comment: I will use it in different clients, so will it make that scoring as default? If I will post without using that in get requests will result will be sorted using score field of doc?

Comment: What I want is to make _score * doc[score] permanent for all requests.

Comment: Your question stated `_score to be equal to score field`, so it's different than multiplying it by the score field: `_score * doc[score]`. Let me update my answer accordingly. As for making the score "permanent", I don't think there's a way to achieve it, however, you could use a search template containing the scoring function so that you don't have to specify it each time.

Comment: So, answer is its not possible. The only solution for me looks like adding sort query to url.